# Store several colors and switch from one color to another

Tags: c++, opengl

I would like to store several colors for an object and be able to switch from one color to another at runtime.

For now, I store vertices and colors using VBO and VAO this way :

```
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, _verticesBytesSize, _vertices.data());
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _verticesBytesSize, _colorsBytesSize, _colors1.data());
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _verticesBytesSize+_colorsBytesSize, _colorsBytesSize, _colors2.data());
```

and I create `glVertexAttribPointer' for each of these array of data. Index 0 for vertices and 1 and 2 for colors :

```
...
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ((char*)NULL + (0)));
...
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ((char*)NULL + (_verticesBytesSize)));
...
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ((char*)NULL + (_verticesBytesSize) + (_colorsBytesSize)));
```

In a shader loading function (that manages compilation, shader and program association etc.) I use 'glBindAttribLocation' to specify what are the entries to my shaders/programs :

```
glBindAttribLocation(_program, 0, "in_Vertex");
glBindAttribLocation(_program, 1, "in_Color");
```

If I use index 1, "in_Color" will be color1 while if I use index 2, "in_Color" will be color2.

It works fine. My question is : is that the best way to do that ? I mean, I have to load my shaders each time I want to change color giving to the loading shader function the index of the glVertexAttribPointer to use.

Shaders are quite new for me that's why I'm asking for good practices.

Comment: *"I have to load my shaders each time "*  - Why? Do the vertex attribute specification dependent on the shader, but don't linke the shader for the specification. That's much cheaper. It is common to specify the attribute location by [Layout Qualifiers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Vertex_shader_attribute_index)

Comment: I like this way of doing it but I don't understand how to change color at runtime ? Do I have to produce two vertex shaders, one for the first color and one for the second ? Then I `glAttachShader' these shaders to two different programs and switch programs to change colors ?

Comment: No, one shader program! use 2 different [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) (or call `glVertexAttribPointer` at runtime)

Comment: Can you post an answer with such a shader using two different Vertex Array Object please ? I have trouble understanding how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to generate 2 different [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object).

You've on shader program with the following attribute locations:

> ```cpp
> glBindAttribLocation(_program, 0, "in_Vertex");
> glBindAttribLocation(_program, 1, "in_Color");
> ```

And on buffer:

> ```cpp
> glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, _verticesBytesSize, _vertices.data());
> glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _verticesBytesSize, _colorsBytesSize, _colors1.data());
> glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _verticesBytesSize+_colorsBytesSize, _colorsBytesSize, _colors2.data());
> ```

Create 2 vertex array objects. Both associate the color to the attribute index 1, but they use different buffer offsets:

```cpp
GLuint vao[2];
glGenVertexArrays(2, &vao);

glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ((char*)NULL + (0)));
int offset = _verticesBytesSize;
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ((char*)NULL + offset ));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glBindVertexArray(vao[1]);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ((char*)NULL + (0)));
int offset = _verticesBytesSize + _colorsBytesSize;
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ((char*)NULL + offset));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Bind the proper vertex array object when you draw the mesh. In the following `i` is either 0 or 1:

```cpp
glBindVertexArray( vao[i] );
glDrawArrays(...);
```

Comment: Pfff I'm stupid... the location in the shader's layout qualifier will be the same for both colors ! Thank's a lot !

Answer (score 2):

You'd be better off simply changing the attribute binding point for the colour attribute 1 (which would be a lot easier than re-compiling the shader each time!).

```
if(renderingUsingColor1)
{
  glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ((char*)NULL + (_verticesBytesSize)));
}
else
{
  glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ((char*)NULL + (_verticesBytesSize) + (_colorsBytesSize)));
}
```